# Geometric Interpretation of Jacobi identity for cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, cross-product

Is there a geometric "reason" for the Jacobi identity for cross products? Some geometric equality of some area ...?

All proofs I know work by some form of linear algebra (or use the interpretation as a Lie algebra ...)

Answer (score 1):

One geometric interpretation is that the altitudes of a triangle intersect in a single point.

You can read about it here: http://olympiads.mccme.ru/lktg/2006/4/ or here: http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~khudian/Etudes/Geometry/jacidentandheights1.pdf