# Geometric proof for triple vector product Jacobi identity

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis, cross-product

I believe the vector identity
$\vec{a} \times (\vec{b} \times \vec{c}) + \vec{b} \times (\vec{c} \times \vec{a}) + \vec{c} \times (\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) = 0$
is called the Jacobi identity and I know the proof.

Does anybody know of some elegant geometrical picture to illustrate why the identity is true?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556009/geometric-interpretation-of-jacobi-identity-for-cross-product

Comment: perhaps, but it doesn't seem there is an adequate answer in the duplicate.

Comment: Ýes a duplicate. I found an idea to use the property that the cross product gives a polarity on the real projective plane, when the vectors $\lambda \vec{a}$ etc. are considered as homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: If three vectors add to zero, that means if you draw the vectors tip-to-tail then they'll form a triangle. That means they must all lie in one plane. So a geometrical proof would probably aim to construct a line perpendicular to this plane.

Comment: In the link in the answer of the other question, the property of a triangle that its altitudes are concurrent is used and $A + B + C = 0$ gives the configuration of a triangle in a plane.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an abstract nonsense proof:

The vector
$$\vec T(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}):=\vec{a} \times (\vec{b} \times \vec{c}) + \vec{b} \times (\vec{c} \times \vec{a}) + \vec{c} \times (\vec{a} \times \vec{b})$$
is easily seen to be a skew trilinear function of the three vector variables $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, $\vec{c}$. It follows that its coordinates $T_i$ are three real-valued such functions, whence are multiples of the determinant function (so-called triple vector product) $[\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}]$ with factors $\lambda_i$ independent of $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, $\vec{c}$. Putting $\vec{p}:=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$ we therefore  have
$$\vec T(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c})=[\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}]\>\vec{p}$$
with a *universal vector* $\vec{p}$. This only makes sense when $\vec{p}=\vec{0}$.

Comment: Why is it that the skew real-valued functions must be multiples of the triple vector product?

Comment: It is a basic fact of multilinear algebra that in ${\mathbb R}^n$ there is, up to a constant factor, exactly one such skew $n$-linear function, also called *volume form*.

Comment: I followed the argument until the last sentence. Why is it true that this only makes sense when $p = 0$? My guess is that suitable choices of particular $a,b,c$ would yield a contradiction if $p\not = 0$, but I'm not sure which choices are the right ones.

Comment: @MatthewKvalheim: Yes, use $$\vec{a} = \vec{i}, \vec{b} = \vec{j}, \vec{c} = \vec{k}$$.

Answer (score 5):

This attempt at an answer is geometric in the sense that it is stated in terms of vectors and not components.

Geometrically the double-cross product is given by 
$$\vec{a} \times (\vec{b} \times \vec{c}) = (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c}) \vec{b}- (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}) \vec{c}.$$
This shows three things:

1. $\vec{a} \times (\vec{b} \times \vec{c}) = (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c}) \vec{b}- (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}) \vec{c}$ falls in the plane spanned by $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$
2. $\vec{b} \times (\vec{c} \times \vec{a}) = (\vec{b} \cdot \vec{a}) \vec{c}- (\vec{b} \cdot \vec{c}) \vec{a}$ falls in the plane spanned by $\vec{c}$ and $\vec{a}$
3. $\vec{c} \times (\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) = (\vec{c} \cdot \vec{b}) \vec{a} - (\vec{c} \cdot \vec{a}) \vec{b}$ falls in the plane spanned by $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$

Add these relations the terms in the $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ directions cancel thus revealing the Jacobi Identity.

We could visualize these in terms of three planes which intersect along the directions $\vec{a},\vec{b}, \vec{c}$. I illustrate as if they are orthogonal as to keep the picture manageable. The idea here is the lengths of the orange, purple and cyan arrows are indicative of the dot-products which appear in the spans.

[image]

Comment: The basic geometric idea here is also used in this http://math.stackexchange.com/a/400732/36530

Comment: This answer is fine in terms of explaining the direction of the vector triple product. But could you explain why the *magnitude* of each component is the way it is? i.e = the dot product of two other vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to Matthew Kvalheim. Let $R:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a rotation on $\mathbb{R}^3$ around a certain axis. Then $(R\vec{a}\times R\vec{b})=R(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})$. From here and the definition of the map $\vec{T}$ we have that
$$
\vec{T}(R\vec{a},R\vec{b},R\vec{c})=R\vec{T}(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}).
$$
From the expression in terms of $\vec{p}$ of the map $\vec{T}$ and the fact that $[R\vec{a},R\vec{b},R\vec{c}]=[\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}]$, one obtains
$$
\vec{T}(R\vec{a},R\vec{b},R\vec{c})=[R\vec{a},R\vec{b},R\vec{c}]\vec{p}=[\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}]\vec{p}=\vec{T}(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}).
$$
Comparing the above expressions, we obtain that
$$
R\vec{T}(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c})=\vec{T}(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c})
$$
for every $R$, which means that $\vec{T}(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c})=0$ for arbitrary $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ and $\vec{p}=0$ always.